# Setting font types from self defined font families

Tags: fontspec

I have several self defined font families as follows:

```
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\newfontfamily\anonymous{AnonymousPro}[
Path            =   ./Fonts/Anonymous/,
Extension       =   .ttf,
UprightFont     =   *-Regular,
BoldFont        =   *-Bold,
ItalicFont      =   *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont  =   *-BoldItalic
]  


\newfontfamily\galano{Galano-Classic}[
Path            =   ./Fonts/Galano/,
Extension       =   .otf,
UprightFont     =   *,
BoldFont        =   *-Bold,
]
```

etc.

This lets me almost seamlessly switch fonts by making a block and calling the font family name, e.g.

```
{\anonymous nice monospaced font}
```

My question is how can I now tell LaTeX (XeLaTeX compiled) to use the font family `\anonymous` for monospace?

I know, using `fontspec`, I have to state:

```
\setmainfont{Lato}[
Path            =   ./Fonts/Lato/,
Extension       =   .ttf,
UprightFont     =   *-Light,
BoldFont        =   *-Regular ,
ItalicFont      =   *-LightItalic ,
BoldItalicFont  =   *-Italic
]
```

rather than `\setmainfont{\lato}` (defined as the other families above).

So how can I do this simply?

Comment: Avoid loading `xlxtra` and `xunicode`.

Comment: @egreg how come?

Comment: Trust me. It used to be recommended; no longer since a few years ago

Comment: but what if you need unicode characters? and why is it no longer recommended?

Comment: The `xunicode` package is automatically loaded by `fontspec` (if necessary, and it will no longer be in future times). The `xltxtra` package now just adds some rarely needed functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\defaultfontfeatures` with an optional argument to define a font name and then use that name:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[AnonymousPro]
  {
    Extension      = .ttf                       ,
    BoldFont       = AnonymousPro-Bold          ,
    ItalicFont     = AnonymousPro-BoldItalic    ,
    BoldItalicFont = AnonymousPro-Italic        ,
    UprightFont    = AnonymousPro-Regular       ,
  }

\setmonofont{AnonymousPro}

\newfontfamily\anonymous{AnonymousPro}

\begin{document}
Roman Text, \texttt{Monotype text}\par
{\fontspec{AnonymousPro} Monotype text}, roman text\par
{\anonymous Monotype text}, roman text

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Why set default font features first? Can I define multiple font families that way?

Comment: @SumNeuron - Yes, e.g. load `xcolor`and define`\defaultfontfeatures[AnonymousPro2]{Color = blue , ...}`.  Then use `{\fontspec{AnonymousPro2} Monotype text}` in your text.